# Copy Each Identity Of Inserted Records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two table
first:

```
Table:     TBL#Sell

   SellId    ClientId    ProductId
                1           3
                3           5
                4            6
```

second:

```
 Table: TBL#Sell2

    SellId      ClientId       ProductId
```

Now I want to copy every record of first table to second one.
"SellId" column in second table (Sell2.SellId) is Auto Increment (Identity).

for any insert the TBL#Sell2.SellId will set with new identity and i must store the identity in TBL#Sell1.SellId
Is it clear?
What is the solution? , plz.
**thanks**

**I want to store TBL#Sell2.SellId in TBL#Sell.SellId**

Comment: it is not clear where do you want to store the TBL#Sell1.SellId

Comment: I want to store TBL#Sell2.SellId in TBL#Sell.SellId

Comment: Is the combination of ClientId and ProductId unique in TBL#Sell?

Comment: lo siento.No**********************

Comment: Is TBL#Sell2 empty before you copy the rows? Are all SellId in TBLSell empty before copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *triggers* :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look at the OUTPUT clause in Books Online.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have more ways to perform this task.

You could write a stored procedure that for every record in table1 write to table2 and then update table1 getting the identity value from [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Or another way could be, if the couple ClientId/ProductId is a key, to do an insert and then an update with something like that:

```
insert into TBL#Sell2
select SellId, ClientId, ProductId from TBL#Sell

upadte TBL#Sell
set TBL#Sell.SellId = TBL#Sell2.SellId
from TBL#Sell T1 join TBL#Sell2 T2
on T1.ClientId = T2.ClientId and T1.ProductId  = T2.ProductId
```

**EDIT** Replaced @@Identity with SCOPE_IDENTITY

Comment: clientid/productid is not a key

Comment: Which is the key in the first table?

Comment: Never use @@identity and  don't teach people to use it. It does not always return the correct value and will break your data integrity.

Comment: right, i replaced with scope_identity which should be the right one to use

Answer (score 0):

It `TBL#Sell2` is empty you basically only want to give a number to each row in `TBL#Sell`. You can do that without using `TBL#Sell2`.

Add a temporary identity column, move the values to to `SellId`, remove the temp column.

```
alter table TBL#Sell add SellId_tmp int not null identity
go
update TBL#Sell set SellId = SellId_tmp
go
alter table TBL#Sell drop column SellId_tmp
```

Another way is to use a CTE with row_number().

```
;with cte as
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(order by (select(1))) as rn
  from TBL#Sell
) 
update cte set
  SellId = rn
```