# Matching each row of one table with one row of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I 've got a table:

```
TABLE_A
-----------  
Sc Cl Pr Br
-----------
1  1  1  NULL
2  1  1  NULL
1  2  2  NULL
2  2  2  NULL
```

(Sc, Cl, Pr) is a candidate key

In order to assign values to the field Br (take this for granted it cannot change) I insert these rows into a TABLE_B with 3 fields (Br, Cl, Pr) with field Br auto incremented (to make things simpler assume that TABLE_B is empty and TABLE_A contains only the above rows). So i do something like that

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (Cl, Pr) SELECT Cl, Pr FROM TABLE_A
```

Now I want to assign the auto generated TABLE_B.Br to TABLE_A.Br in such a way that

`TABLE_B.Cl = TABLE_A.Cl AND TABLE_B.Pr = TABLE_A.Pr`

AND for every two rows of TABLE_A t1, t2 that

```
t1.Cl = t2.Cl AND t1.Pr = t2.Pr  AND t1.Sc <> t2.Sc => t1.Br <> t2.Br
```

PS 1: I hope this is not too confusing :(

PS 2: The only quick and easy solution i 've find is to add a field in TABLE_B (Sc) then a simple join between the tables would do the job. But adding a column is not an option.

Comment: It might be too confusing...  Maybe it would help to see what the resulting table data would be once it was done?

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server do you use?

Comment: Have a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830229/copy-each-identity-of-inserted-records/5831028#5831028. Another guy asking almost the same question. I would really like to know why the design of these tables are like this. Does not really make any sense at all.

Comment: @Mikael: thnx. It smells like homework. For a subject taught by a devious teacher.

Comment: @ypercube, unfortunately this is not a homework but a real situation, result of previous bad designing and denial to change the schema of the database. This is just an abstract version of the real problem specified as precisely as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more like a puzzle than a problem. Can't you drop the column `Br` and add it again as auto incrementing one?

Anyway, here's a solution using `ROW_NUMBER()` with `PARTITION` :

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Br = B.Br
FROM
    ( SELECT Cl
           , Pr
           , ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER(PARTITION BY Cl, Pr ORDER BY Sc)
             AS rowNo
           , Br
      FROM TABLE_A
    ) AS A
  JOIN
    ( SELECT Cl
           , Pr
           , ROW_NUMBER()
               OVER(PARTITION BY Cl, Pr ORDER BY Br)
             AS rowNo
           , Br
      FROM TABLE_B
    ) AS B
    ON  A.Cl = B.Cl
    AND A.Pr = B.Pr
    AND A.rowNo = B.rowNo;
```

On second thought, you don't really need `TABLE_B`. You can assign auto values to field `Br` with:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Br = A.rowNo
FROM
    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER(ORDER BY Cl, Pr, Sc)
             AS rowNo
           , Br
      FROM TABLE_A
    ) AS A;
```

Comment: All in all PARTITION BY was what i was looking for in order to create a third field "rowNo" so that (Cl,Pr,rowNow) would be unique. Second solution applies only if (Sc, Cl, Pr) are unique (which are in the defined problem) but in the real problem TABLE_A is the result of a distinct select on the Sc, Cl, Pr where Br is NULL which is repeated (After several insertions of new values)

Answer (score 0):

If you've only got two values for Sc then try these two statements:

```
Update TABLE_A a set br = ( select min( br ) // select lowest br values 
                             from TABLE_B b
                            where a.cl = b.cl
                              and a.pr = b.pr )
 where a.sc = ( select min( sc )             // updating lower sc values
                  from TABLE_A c
                 where a.cl = c.cl
                   and a.pr = c.pr )

Update TABLE_A a set br = ( select max( br ) // select highest br values
                              from TABLE_B b
                             where a.cl = b.cl
                               and a.pr = b.pr )
 where a.sc = ( select max( sc )
                  from TABLE_A c
                 where a.cl = c.cl
                   and a.pr = c.pr )         // update highest sc values
```

Comment: Nope Sc can have multiple values. The TABLE_A is an abstract example of a more complicated table. What i was thinking is to use an temporary table to save the results of the join on Cl and Pr and then find a way to eliminate the extra rows, or eliminate this extra rows on the fly with a where clause but can't think of any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2008 you can use [merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) and [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
declare @T table(Sc int, Cl int, Pr int, Br int);

merge TABLE_B as T
using TABLE_A as S
on 1=0
when not matched then
  insert(Cl, Pr) values(S.Cl, S.Br)
output S.Sc, S.Cl, S.Pr, inserted.Br into @T;

update A
  set Br = T.Br 
from TABLE_A as A 
  inner join @T as T
    on A.Sc = T.Sc and
       A.Cl = T.Cl and
       A.Pr = T.Pr;
```